# Recorrer un excel por columnas PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

tengo que leer un excel y cargar la información a la base de datos con respecto a unos informes, la estructura de informes que envían es fija y es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es tomar A1, luego B2 hasta B8, N cantidad de veces, hice la prueba recorriendo un archivo de texto casi logrando la solución.

```
while(! feof($file)) {
    $i=0;
    $data = array();
    while($i<8){
        $line = fgets($file);
        echo $line. "<br>";
        array_push($data, $line);
        //echo $data[$i];
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    $medida_data=array(            
        'id_solicitud'  => 133,
        'programa'  => 1,
        'orden' => $data[0],  
        'ges' => $data[1],                   
        'dimension' =>$data[2],                   
        'actividades' => $data[3],
        'ejecucion' =>$data[4],
        'fecha_comprometida' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data[5])),
        'fecha_creacion' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'plazo' => $data[6],                   
        'estado' => 1
    );     
    $this->propuestas_model->register_medida_plan($medida_data);
    echo "<br>";
    $i=0;
```

pero no logro dar con la solución para excel.

```
        $reader->open($inputFileName);
        $count = 1;
        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        //Numero de Hojas en el Archivo 
            foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                if($row[0] != ''){
                 if($count > 1) {
                        $data = array(
                            'fecha_edicion' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row[0])),
                            'orden' => $row[1][1],
                            'ges' => $row[2],
                            'dimension' => $row[3],
                            'ejecucion' => $row[4],
                            'actividades' => $row[5],
                            'medios_verificacion' => $row[6]
                           
                        );  
                        //$this->db->insert('medidas',$data);                       
                    }  
                    $count++;                           
                }
            }
```

De momento tengo una forma básica de recorrer el excel, pero va fila por fila y no se como hacer los saltos que requiero para que solo tome los campos precisos.

Comment: Hola, te genera algun mensaje de error o cual es el resultado que obtienes y cual el que deseas?